# How is the light source given in some OpenGL examples created?

Tags: qt, opengl

I have seen some OpenGL examples where a light source is shown. eg .

[image]

I understand the code required to get this kind of lighting effect in my scene, but how is that light source (visible in the top left corner in the example) created here ? Do I need to enable some flag to show the light source as well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no setting/flag to automatically show a light source. You have to render it just like anything else in the scene.

The light source in the example you show looks like it consists of 4 triangles for the outside, and another quad (2 triangles) for the surface that emits the light. You can render these triangles with exactly the same mechanisms used for rendering the cube in this scene, or anything else. Build a VBO with the vertex data, and draw the geometry, with transformations applied if necessary.

Yes, this means that you may use a light source to render a light source. While that may sound strange, it makes complete sense. Once you look at the light source as a geometric object, you can apply lighting to it like you would for all your other objects. At least in this example, the outside polygons of the light source look lighted, while the surface emitting the light looks flat white.